# How to set default form values based on query string, if the form uses AJAX file upload

Tags: 7, forms, files

I have a `Book` content type with a file upload field.
I'm using [Filefield Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module with [Plupload integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) for getting the file upload widget.

I need to set a default value based on the query string passed on `node/add/book` page.

However, the files are uploaded via AJAX, calling the `file/ajax` page, and losing all default values I set. Obviously, custom query string is not present in that call, and when the form is re-generated, I get an error.

Any ideas on how can I make sure that default values stay in the form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post the answer.

To keep the data persistent between AJAX calls, you should store it in the `$form_state` variable. This is how it worked in my case:

1. Check if I already have the data in `$form_state`.
2. If not and if there is query string, get the data, sanitize/validate it and store in `$form_state`.

This way it works even for AJAX calls where query string parameters are not available.